# Running karma test using gulp on visual studio Continuous integration(TFS) issue

Tags: gulp, phantomjs, karma-runner

Running gulp task to test karma works fine in my local machine using visual 
studio Task Runner Explorer or using Command prompt but if fails during 
continuous integration.

Here is the task in the gulp.

```
gulp.task('run-test', function (done) {
     Server.start({
        configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }, function (result) {
      if (result > 0) {
        return done(new Error(`Karma exited with status code ${result}`));
      }
        done();
    });
});
```

Below is the error that I am getting.

```
Starting: gulp run-test
****************************************************************************
C:\Users\issblder\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp.cmd run-test --gulpfile 
C:\BA\263\s\x.y\x.y.Web\gulpfile.js
Using gulpfile C:\BA\263\s\x.y\x.y.Web\gulpfile.js
Starting 'run-test'...
  [33m05 04 2017 10:28:07.848:WARN [proxy]: [39mproxy "/base/Scripts/src/app" normalized to "/base/Scripts/src/app/"
  [33m05 04 2017 10:28:09.051:WARN [watcher]: [39mPattern "C:/BA/263/s/x.y/x.y.Web/Scripts/src/app/**/*.css" does not match any file.
  [32m05 04 2017 10:28:10.707:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v1.5.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
  [32m05 04 2017 10:28:10.707:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
  [32m05 04 2017 10:28:10.738:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser PhantomJS
  [32m05 04 2017 10:28:14.399:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: 
  [39mConnected on socket llGPa-KBXnovTYHkAAAA with id 95283473
  [33m05 04 2017 10:28:14.500:WARN [web-server]: [39m404: /base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
[1A[2KPhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0 secs / 0 secs)
'run-test' errored after 7.41 s
Error: Karma exited with status code 1
  at C:\BA\263\s\x.y\x.y.Web\gulpfile.js:33:25
  at removeAllListeners (C:\BA\263\s\x.y\x.y.Web\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:380:7)
  at Server.<anonymous> (C:\BA\263\s\x.y\x.y.Web\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:391:9)
  at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
  at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
  at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
  at emitCloseNT (net.js:1521:8)
  at nextTickCallbackWith1Arg (node.js:431:9)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)

Gulp failed with error: C:\Users\issblder\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp.cmd failed with return code: 1

****************************************************************************
Finishing: gulp run-test.
```

I am using these dev dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.46",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.8",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-delete-lines": "^0.0.7",
    "gulp-inject-string": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-ngc": "^0.1.2",
    "gulp-size": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.9.1",
    "gulp-tslint": "^7.0.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-xml-reporter": "^0.1.4",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
    "rollup": "^0.41.4",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "rollup-stream": "^1.19.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.7.2",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "typings": "^2.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
},
```

Comment: Which CI system are you using? TFS? Jenkins? VSTS? Something else?

Comment: I am using visual studio online TFS

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?